# to to get data from specific index in multidimensional array to avoid use of many foreach loops

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to get data in from multidimensional array without using foreach 
i tried using in_array() function but not worked

```
$abc =  array()
in_array($abc , $private_job->cities)

in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given
```

on using `$private_job->cities` got the following result

```
Collection {#408 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => city {#416 ▼
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:2 [▼
        "id" => 7
        "city_name" => "Gujranwala"
    ]

    }
    1 => city {#417 ▼
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:2 [▶]
      #original: array:4 [▼
        "id" => 4
        "city_name" => "Islamabad"
        "pivot_private_jobabd_id" => 53
        "pivot_city_id" => 4
      ]

    }
  ]
}
```

whereas i am interested in getting

```
"id" => 7
"id" => 4
```

in an an `array`

Comment: $array[0]['id'] or $array[1]['id']

Comment: what if i had 100 records @clearshot66

Comment: Then you need to use a foreach or a for loop, there's no direct access to an array dynamically without one of those two unless you write a function to grab what I just told you and again, ran it with a loop of some sort. Also, in_array only works with single level arrays, not multidimensionals

Comment: use for loop with i counter

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $private_job->cities->map(function($data){
   return $data['id'];
})->all();
```